# Symfony apply to new booking

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How can I apply in symfony to a new booking using doctrine with a entity for user a entity for restaurant and a entity for table

I didn't try hard enough

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not very clear, it needs maybe  details about what you want to achieve and what problems you are facing but here is a way to go :

you can create entities in Symfony with the help of Doctrine and
generate the User, Restaurant, Table and the Booking entities using the Symfony console command `bin/console make:entity.`

You will be asked in your terminal what kind of properties you want for the entity.
You can add
You can add for the User a OneToMany relationship to represent the user's bookings. In the Restaurant entity, add a OneToMany relationship to represent the restaurant's bookings. In the Table entity, add a OneToMany relationship to represent the table's bookings (these are just examples.)

Finally, generate your database with the command
`bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.